# SendEmailNotifictaion throwing smtphost error

Tags: pega

I am using SendEmailNotification via call to send email. It is throwing an error

**"List of params for Method or activity that this step is calling— Property @baseclass.gmail is undefined."**

This is when I used smtp.gmail.com as smtphodt. When I change it to smtp.yahoo.com it says **"List of params for Method or activity that this step is calling— Property @baseclass.yahoo is undefined."**

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Definitely  there  is a problem in property reference . Could share the screenshot of each step of the activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got solved by putting smtp.gmail.com in double quotes.